# Trouble adding Jquery Datatables Excel / Print Buttons

Tags: datatables

I used the Jquery Datatable Initializer on their website, added the cdn's and updated the jquery as follows.

[image]

```
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('vendor/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('vendor/js-datepicker/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('vendor/js-datepicker/daterangepicker.js') }}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
        src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.12.1/b-2.2.3/b-colvis-2.2.3/b-html5-2.2.3/r-2.3.0/datatables.min.js">
    </script>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.12.1/b-2.2.3/b-colvis-2.2.3/b-html5-2.2.3/b-print-2.2.3/r-2.3.0/datatables.min.css"/>
```

```
$table = $('#client_search').DataTable( {
    responsive: true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {extend:'colvis',text:'Show/Hide Columns'},
        'pageLength',
        'print',
        'excelHtml5',
    
    ]
   
} );

$("#client_search").width("100%");
```

You can see that they aren't showing up...

[image]

Comment: You may have some conflicting styles and/or functions in your included libraries. When I use the resources from your "download" screenshot (plus jQuery 3, which you had not checked) - and when I do _not_ use any of the other resources you show in your code fragment, then the buttons are displayed, using your DataTables code. So, maybe start there, and then add in additional libraries one at a time.

Comment: @andrewJames Jquery 3.6 fixed it, 3.3.1 was the version I had..